# How to open the excel file to take screen shot of the file and close the file which is opened using python

Tags: python, automation

#I used this to open an excel file

os.startfile("filepath")

sleep(10)

#Screenshot

ss=pyautogui.screenshot()

ss.save("savepath")

#close the excel file

os.system("taskkill /im EXCEL.exe")

Here taskkill is killing the excel file which are already in use but i want to close the particular excelfile to close.

And i used wait time to take the screenshot of excel. Can i have a better solution.

1. To open excel
2. Take screenshot of the excel
3. Close the excel file